# Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints. C# Windows forms

Tags: c#, sql-server, firebird

I was working on Firebird Server and SQL Server to update database from the Firebird database to the SQL server database. This update was done using a tool called Updater Tool. I have created this tool using C# Windows Application, it was successfully running.

This database contains financial data. The client has provided a Firebird database backup file with data up to 2016, and it was successfully updating the database.

I have restored the backup file successfully on my system, so I have created a setup file and installed it on the client system and I started updating the database. The client has the latest data, it was working and updating SQL database.

It was updating some tables and then got an error *"Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints."* and operation was cancelled.

What I need is, whenever I get this type of error, I want to skip or ignore the error and the remaining part should update the database. How I have created the update tool means,

1. I have created arrays that store all table columns. This is done because only selected columns from Firebird database table columns were updated in the SQL Server database.
2. Each table contains 2 primary key columns with this I have created a comparison of the two databases to find which data is not present in the SQL Server database. The compared table rows are stored in `DataTable`.
3. The updating is done by selecting a date. In updater tool, I have provided a datetimepicker, the client can select the date and update his database. What client has done means that the SQL Server database was updated up to 2015 and client wants to update data from 2017 that means client left 2016 data, so in database comparison it gets the entire data above 2017. Here is a link, based on this I have created comparison method [Database Comparison](http://canlu.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-compare-two-datatables-in-adonet.html).
4. Below is the code how I update the database

   ```
   public void UpdateToDatabse(DataTable table, string selectQuery, ArrayList columnNames, string tableName)
   {
       string fbSelectStatementQuery;
       int insertedCount = 0;
       int notInsertedCount = 0;
       listBox1.Items.Add("Total Rows to update " + table.Rows.Count); 
       using (FbConnection fbconn = getFbConnection(textBox1.Text))
       {
           FbCommand fbcmd = new FbCommand();
           fbcmd.Connection = fbconn;
           for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
           {
               if (tableName == "COMPDATA" || tableName == "COMPMAS")
               {
                   fbSelectStatementQuery = @"" + selectQuery
                   + " Where \"" + table.Columns[0].ColumnName + "\"='" + table.Rows[i][0] + "'";
                   fbcmd.CommandText = fbSelectStatementQuery;
               }
               else if (tableName == "DLYPRICEBSE" || tableName == "DLYPRICENSE")
               {
                   fbSelectStatementQuery = @"" + selectQuery
                  + " Where \"" + table.Columns[0].ColumnName + "\"='" + table.Rows[i][0] + "' and \""
                  + table.Columns[1].ColumnName + "\"='" + Convert.ToDateTime(table.Rows[i][1]).ToShortDateString() + "' and \""
                  + table.Columns[2].ColumnName + "\"='" + table.Rows[i][2] + "' and \""
                  + table.Columns[3].ColumnName + "\"='" + table.Rows[i][3] + "' and \""
                  + table.Columns[4].ColumnName + "\"='" + table.Rows[i][4] + "' and \""
                  + table.Columns[5].ColumnName + "\"='" + table.Rows[i][5] + "' and \""
                  + table.Columns[6].ColumnName + "\"='" + table.Rows[i][6] + "' and \""
                  + table.Columns[7].ColumnName + "\"='" + table.Rows[i][7] + "' and \""
                  + table.Columns[8].ColumnName + "\"='" + table.Rows[i][8] + "' and \""
                  + table.Columns[9].ColumnName + "\"='" + table.Rows[i][9] + "' and \""
                  + table.Columns[10].ColumnName + "\"='" + table.Rows[i][10] + "' and \""
                  + table.Columns[11].ColumnName + "\"='" + table.Rows[i][11] + "' and \""
                  + table.Columns[12].ColumnName + "\"='" + table.Rows[i][12] + "' and \""
                  + table.Columns[13].ColumnName + "\"='" + table.Rows[i][13] + "' and \""
                  + table.Columns[14].ColumnName + "\"='" + table.Rows[i][14] + "' and \""
                  + table.Columns[15].ColumnName + "\"='" + table.Rows[i][15] + "'";
                   fbcmd.CommandText = fbSelectStatementQuery;
               }
               else if (tableName == "EQTYHIS")
               {
                   fbSelectStatementQuery = @"" + selectQuery
                   + " Where \"" + table.Columns[0].ColumnName + "\"='" + table.Rows[i][0] + "' and \""
                   + table.Columns[1].ColumnName + "\"='" + Convert.ToDateTime(table.Rows[i][1]).ToShortDateString() + "' ";
                   fbcmd.CommandText = fbSelectStatementQuery;
               }
               else
               {
                   fbSelectStatementQuery = @"" + selectQuery
                   + " Where \"" + table.Columns[0].ColumnName + "\"='" + table.Rows[i][0] + "' and \""
                   + table.Columns[1].ColumnName + "\"='" + table.Rows[i][1] + "' ";
                   fbcmd.CommandText = fbSelectStatementQuery;
               }
               using (FbDataReader fbreader = fbcmd.ExecuteReader())
               {
                   while (fbreader.Read())
                   {
                       string colValues = @"( ";
                       string columns = @"";
                       int j = 0;
                       while (j < columnNames.Count)
                       {
                           if (j < columnNames.Count - 1)
                           {
                               columns += "\"" + columnNames[j] + "\"" + ", ";
                               colValues += "'" + ((Object)fbreader[columnNames[j].ToString()]) + "', ";
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               columns += "\"" + columnNames[j] + "\"";
                               colValues += "'" + fbreader[columnNames[j].ToString()] + "' )";
                           }
                           j++;
                       }

                       string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Data." + tableName + " (" + columns + ") VALUES " + colValues;
                       using (SqlConnection sqlconn = getSqlConncetion())
                       {
                           try
                           {
                               SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, sqlconn);
                               sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                               sqlconn.Close();
                               insertedCount++;
                           }
                           catch (Exception ex)
                           {
                               notInsertedCount++;
                               //MessageBox.Show("Not Inserted-->" + ex.Message);
                               //listBox1.Items.Add(fbreader["CO_CODE"] + ex.Message);                  
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   fbreader.Close();
               }
           }
           listBox1.Items.Add(insertedCount + " Rows are Updated....");
           if (notInsertedCount > 0)
           {
               listBox1.Items.Add(notInsertedCount + " Rows are not Updated....");
               listBox1.Items.Add("....");
           }
           else
           {
               listBox1.Items.Add("....");
           }
           //MessageBox.Show(insertedCount + " Rows are Updated in IBDMaster table " + tableName);
           fbconn.Close();
       }
       return;
   }
   ```

First, I want to skip or ignore the error I'm getting.

Second, the database code is performing slowly, is there any method to do a fast update to the database.

Comment: It sounds like you are disabling constraints in SQL Server before you attempt to merge data, and then re-enable them after you are done. Is that right? In that case there is probably something wrong with your duplicate detection. However, as it stands your question is far too broad with way too many code.

Comment: Can you explain about what i got the error is, here is f`    failed to enable constraints. one or more rows contains values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints` from this error what i know means **Violation non-null** means primary-key row contains null value and **Unique** means in primary key columns we cannot insert duplicate value and **Foreign-key Constraints** can tell me about this why we will get this type error.

Comment: It does not necessary to happen on primary keys. There are "PK" constraints, and there are "FK constraints" and there are "Unique" constraints and "Check" constraints.... Those are different ones. Thewre is no "not-null constraint" though. See - https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-ddl-tbl.html#fblangref25-ddl-tbl-constraints - We do not know what exact command was sent to the server when the tool issued that error, nor what was the error text as the server reported it. It is all mere blinded guesswork we can do without information

Comment: "the database code is performing slowly" - since you disabled the constraints you probably also disabled indexes that implemented those constraints, and thus every operation with the tables goes as "natural scan" - on every command the server has to pick every row one by one to check if it will work with this row or skip it. That surely is slow, but lacking indexes the server can not know where the rows every command needs are situated and can only "natural scan". That truly up-scales badly.

Comment: @Arioch'The The error is a SQL Server error (or maybe a C# DataTable error?), not a Firebird error, so linking to the Firebird documentation is not that useful.

Comment: so what i have to do now what changes should be done

Comment: You have to find, which specific SQL command, which exactly constraint throws this error. Then you would have to analyze the data to see how to fix that violation. Then you would have to implement this fix to the data - and to the updater program.

Comment: Thank you for information "@Arioch", so let know

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel how to access the database back file which is in other or client system, i have tried this firebird connection string to connect remotely                `string ConnectionString = "User ID=sysdba;Password=masterkey;Database=192.168.1.19:50800:D:\\Company Data\\CLINEDB.CMP;DataSource=192.168.1.19;Charset=NONE;Server Type=1;"` i am getting error like **unable to complete network request to host "50800". Failed  to establish a connection**.

Comment: @Amarnath Please ask a new question for that. But I'll give you a hint: that connection string is incorrect, you shouldn't put everything in the key `Database`. See https://www.connectionstrings.com/firebird/ for examples.